# Returning gsl::span from function

Tags: c++, c++14, gsl

I am trying to print a span returned from a function but it isn't catching the data. How do you correctly return a span from a function?

```
#include <gsl/span>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

gsl::span<int> res(){
    std::array<int, 3> str{100, 200,300};
    gsl::span<int> a{str};
    return gsl::span<int>(a.data(), a.size());
}
int main() {
    auto test{res()};
    for (const auto &i: test)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Content of `span` can be accessed only as long as buffer referenced by `span` remains valid. In this case it references an object that goes out of scope. So you should return `str` directly, or use `vector`, or something that actually provides storage.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is than `span` doesn't own values, so you return dangling span.

You have to return `std::array` (by value) which owns the value.

Comment: Another option is to create the array somewhere where it would last, e.g. on the heap, and then return the span. But then you shouldn't forget to properly manage this memory, i.e. take care of when the array will be deleted.

Comment: @Ruslan: `static str` would be an alternative. Making allocation to return `span`  is problematic as we won't expect to have to delete content of `span`. span is really a view and shouldn't be related to ownership

Comment: Well yes, I was rather thinking of the allocating function being a method of some class that would manage this object, not that the caller would delete the pointee of the span.

Comment: would it be possible to pass span by reference param and return value by that means

Comment: @tester123: unsure what you mean exactly, but remember than span is a single view without ownership.